asyncio issue - I can't run two processes simultaniously
I am trying to work with asyncio.
I want to count time until arduino serial is read. I send the arduino serial externally using an hardware trigger.
my code is:
import asyncio
from Classes.Arduino_class import ArduinoController


async def wait_for_serial(ard):
    print('entered function')
    data = await ard.read_data()
    return data


async def main():
    ard = ArduinoController()
    task = asyncio.create_task(wait_for_serial(ard))
    ind = 0
    while True:
        print(ind)
        ind += 1
        if task.done():
            result = await task
            print(f"Got signal from Arduino: {result}")
            break
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())


The Arduino class is:
class ArduinoController:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ard = serial.Serial('COM7', 2000000)
        time.sleep(0.2)

    async def read_data(self):
        return self.ard.read().decode()

    def write_data(self, val):
        self.ard.write(val.encode())


ard.read() command is a command which blocks the code until data is read.
I tried several configurations for this simple script, but i just couldnt find the correct one.
what usually happens is that the script prints "0", then, "entered function", and then stops until i send the arduino serial.

Since self.ard.read() is blocking, you need to modify the read_data method so that it can somehow initiate and await the completion of the read call without blocking other asyncio tasks:
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
...

NUM_CONCURRENT_READ_WRITE_REQUESTS = 1  # Size of the thread pool
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(NUM_CONCURRENT_READ_WRITE_REQUESTS)

...

class class ArduinoController:
    ...

    async def read_data(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, self.ard.read)
        return data.decode()

    ...

The actual read is now occuring in another thread and so the current thread is not blocked. You might wish to modify the write_data method to be an async method using the same technique above if you do not want to block on writes.

Thanks. Eventually i switched to working completely with threading.

Did you try my suggestion anyway?
